# How do you subtract colors and divide them by irrational numbers? (Gluons)

Tags: hilbert-space, quantum-chromodynamics, lie-algebra, gluons

There is a gluon that is
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} (red \cdot\overline{red} + blue\cdot\overline{blue} - 2\cdot green \cdot\overline{green})$$
This confuses me because I do not understand how adding and subtracting and dividing these colors would work. I know that in matrix form it is 
$$ A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2
\end{pmatrix}$$
This still confuses me, please help me.
This is the 8th Gell-Mann matrix.

Answer (score 2):

What you are writing as *red* is actually a quantum mechanical state, which is a vector in a Hilbert space. What you are writing as a dot is something called a tensor product; it produces a vector in another Hilbert space. You can add and subtract the vectors in Hilbert spaces, and you can multiply them by scalars like $2$ or $1/\sqrt 3$, just like in any vector space.