# In Hilbert space what vectors are the gluon colors red, anti-red, blue, anti-blue, green, and anti-green?

Tags: hilbert-space, gluons

When I asked the question [How do you subtract colors and divide them by irrational numbers? (Gluons)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/511226/how-do-you-subtract-colors-and-divide-them-by-irrational-numbers-gluons) I got the answer that all these colors were vectors in Hilbert space, I want to know which vectors these colors are in Hilbert space, and what is Hilbert space.

Comment: I think this question might be too broad: you're asking us to explain the basics of quantum mechanics. It's the sort of question you answer with a textbook, not in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Are you familiar with the representations of SU(3)?

Comment: @Javier could you give me a link that would explain this to me?

Comment: @YuzurihaInori I have read about it and found out it is related to gluons but do not understand it

Comment: @Yay This might help you out https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10403/mathematically-what-is-color-charge

Comment: @YuzurihaInori I do not understand most of that, but thank you.

Comment: You can think of the vectors you called *red*, *blue*, and *green* as basis vectors similar to $\hat x$, $\hat y$, and $\hat z$ in Euclidean space. They are what other vectors in the space get expressed in terms of.

Comment: @G.Smith thank you for the help, that makes much more sense

Comment: @G.Smith what space are the vectors green, blue, and red in?

Comment: An abstract three-dimensional “color space”, unrelated to the three familiar spatial dimensions. It is the vector space for the fundamental representation $\mathbf{3}$ of $SU(3)$, the gauge group for QCD. The previous sentence may not be intelligible if you haven’t learned about Lie groups and their representations in vector spaces of various dimensions.

Comment: @G.Smith I have not learned about them, I will study them now, thank you.